# add new permalink structure from dynamic page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I created page "play" url: `http://localhost/myweb/play` and inside of page "play" I include PHP code to make the new search from outside Wordpress.

And all worked, if I search from my page "play" the url will be: `http://localhost/myweb/play?m=text+Search&pageno=1`

Now, I want my search result url to be fancy url, like: `http://localhost/myweb/play_text_Search_1.html`

I have tried several add_rewrite_rules but not worked, return "404 not found":

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');
function add_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) 
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^^([^-]*)_([^-]*)\.html$ play&m=$1&pageno=$2[1]', 'top');
    flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}
```

ps: sorry my english is not good

Comment: start by reading the codex page for [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and search this site for other questions using `add_rewrite_rule`, your rule arguments are incorrect. the format you want to rewrite to is very strange, why the .html extension? something like `/play/search-string/1/` makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way I knowit to do this it's using this function:

```
/*
 * Redirects search results from /?s=query to /search/query/, converts %20 to +
 * @link http://txfx.net/wordpress-plugins/nice-search/
 * =======================================  */
function search_redirect() {
  if (is_search() && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin/') === false && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/find/') === false) {
    wp_redirect(home_url('/finde/' . str_replace(array(' ', '%20'), array('+', '+'), urlencode(get_query_var('s')))), 301);
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'search_redirect');
```

It's this you wanna do?

Comment: Beneti: Thanks for your answer.i dont use wordpress search, i created new custom search page who searching to outside wordpress (no wordpress database query). thanks rick.